# How to fix error code: -1000 in Facebook Video Sharing

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am doing the video Sharing using Graph API.
For this I used the following [sample code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/719260d0b045f7d7d8ac4aec9a2a14b40ecc77a6).

but After integrating I found the **error code 1000**,

How can I solve this?

Share your ideas...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1000  API_EC_EVENT_INVALID_TIME   Invalid time for an event.  events.edit

I would presume the time/date you're passing into when creating the event is incorrect.